# Array of str objects into a single int array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am reading the contents of a file and the resulting array is:

```
arr = ['[ 74  73  74  74  73  73  73  74  74  73  74  73 147  74  73]', '[ 74  73  74 147  74  73  73  74  73  74  74  73  73  73  74]', '[ 73 147  74  74  73 147  74  73  73  74  73  74  74  73]', '[73 73 74 73 74 73 74 73 73 74 73 74 74 73 73 74]']
```

I want a single int array like:

```
final_arr = [74,73,74,74,73,73,73,74,74,73,74,73,147,74,73,74,73,74,147,74,73,73,74,73,74,74,73,73,73,74,73,147,74,74,73,147,74,73,73,74,73,74,74,73,73,73,74,73,74,73,74,73,73,74,73,74,74,73,73,74]
```

Could someone guide as to how to obtain the final output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a nested list comprehension :

```
>>> [t for j in [map(int,i.strip('[]').split()) for i in arr] for t in j]
[74, 73, 74, 74, 73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 73, 74, 73, 147, 74, 73, 74, 73, 74, 147, 74, 73, 73, 74, 73, 74, 74, 73, 73, 73, 74, 73, 147, 74, 74, 73, 147, 74, 73, 73, 74, 73, 74, 74, 73, 73, 73, 74, 73, 74, 73, 74, 73, 73, 74, 73, 74, 74, 73, 73, 74]
```

Note that your final expected array hasn't a correct format and there isn't such data structure in python.

Comment: Thanks.. That worked like a charm!! And yes you are right about the final expected format. I have edited the post accordingly..

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ['[ 74  73  74  74  73  73  73  74  74  73  74  73 147  74  73]', '[ 74  73  74 147  74  73  73  74  73  74  74  73  73  73  74]', '[ 73 147  74  74  73 147  74  73  73  74  73  74  74  73]', '[73 73 74 73 74 73 74 73 73 74 73 74 74 73 73 74]']
final_arr = []

for a in arr:
     _a  = a.split(" ")
     for e in _a:
         try:
             e = int(e)
             final_arr.append(e)
         except:
             pass

print final_arr
#[74, 73, 74, 74, 73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 73, 74, 73, 147, 74, 74, 73, 74, 147, 74, 73, 73, 74, 73, 74, 74, 73, 73, 73, 73, 147, 74, 74, 73, 147, 74, 73, 73, 74, 73, 74, 74, 73, 74, 73, 74, 73, 74, 73, 73, 74, 73, 74, 74, 73, 73]
```

If you just want to get the number, I recommend the method.

Comment: Thanks @Tony Yang, even your code works just fine.. But I would prefer a one-liner..

Comment: Although my method is very rude, It's available.